# Start npm_lazy on startup

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, npm-lazy

i would like to use npm_lazy as a local for npm.

i installed npm_lazy and all works perfect.

starting the server using

`npm_lazy --config ~/custom_config/npm_lazy.config.js`

works.

but how can i add this command to the startup of the linux server.
i am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

i tried:

`vi /etc/init.d/npm_lazy`

`chmod ugo+x /etc/init.d/npm_lazy`

**npm_lazy**

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/my/script.sh
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo npm_lazy --config ~/custom_config/npm_lazy.config.js
```

finally

`update-rc.d npm_lazy defaults`

Answer (score 0):

create a file called `npm_lazy.desktop` in a folder called `~/.config/autostart` and copy the below code and restart

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=npm_lazy --config ~/custom_config/npm_lazy.config.js
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_IN]=Npm_Lazy
Name=Npm_Lazy
Comment[en_IN]=npm server lazy
Comment=npm lazy server
```